# Which is the image and the area of this set?

Tags: calculus, change-of-variable

Lets have this application defined by:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = u^2-v^2 \\
y = 2uv
\end{cases}
$$

---

Which are the image and the area of $\Omega$ by the transformation of the rectangle $R$, which vertexes are $(1,1), (2,1), (2,3)$ and $(1,3)$ ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will follow the path $(1,1) \rightarrow (2,1) \rightarrow (2,3) \rightarrow (1,3) \rightarrow (1,1)$ and explicitly give the curves in the form $y = f(x)$.

$(1,1) \rightarrow (2,1)$: Here $v = 1$ and $u \in [1,2]$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
x = u^2 -1 \\
y = 2u
\end{cases} 
\Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{x+1}\\
y = 2u
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
y = 2\sqrt{x+1}
$$
for $x \in [0,3]$

$(2,1) \rightarrow (2,3)$: Here $u = 2$ and $v \in [1,3]$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 4 -v^2 \\
y = 4v
\end{cases} 
\Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
v = \sqrt{4-x}\\
y = 4v
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
y = 4\sqrt{4-x}
$$
for $x \in [-5,3]$

$(2,3) \rightarrow (1,3)$: Here $v = 3$ and $u \in [1,2]$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
x = u^2 -9 \\
y = 6u
\end{cases} 
\Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{x+9}\\
y = 6u
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
y = 6\sqrt{x+9}
$$
for $x \in [-8,-5]$

$(1,3) \rightarrow (1,1)$: Here $u = 1$ and $v \in [1,3]$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 1 -v^2 \\
y = 2v
\end{cases} 
\Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{1-x}\\
y = 2v
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
y = 2\sqrt{1-x}
$$
for $x \in [-8,0]$

See the [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B2*Sqrt%5Bx%2B1%5D,4*Sqrt%5B4-x%5D,6*Sqrt%5Bx%2B9%5D,2*Sqrt%5B1-x%5D%7D,%7Bx,-9,9%7D%5D) on WA.